# Apply acceleration that is always opposite to the velocity.

Tags: vectors

I have 2 functions for the $x$ and $y$ components of the velocity of an object ($z$ should always be $0$ in this case)

$$V_x(t)=v_{xi}+\int_0^ta_x(t')dt'$$

$$V_y(t)=v_{yi}+\int_0^t-g+a_y(t')dt'$$

and a function for the magnitude of $a(t)$:

$$a(t)=\frac{T}{m-t\frac{T}{I\cdot g_0}}$$

$a(t)$ is always in the opposite direction of $V(t)$.

How could I replace $a_x(t)$ and $a_y(t)$ in the functions $V_x(t)$ and $V_y(t)$ so that $a$ has the magnitude defined by its function at time t but in the opposite direction of $V$? In other words, how could I get the component functions of $a(t)$ so that it is the opposite direction of $V(t)$ at all t?

I tried setting up the functions like:

$$V_x(t)=v_{xi}+\int_0^ta(t')\cos(\theta)dt'$$

$$V_y(t)=v_{yi}+\int_0^t-g+a(t')\sin(\theta)dt'$$

but then $\theta$ would have to be equal to something like $\tan^{-1}(\frac{V_y(t)}{V_x(t)})$ which would require me to already know $V_x(t)$ and $V_x(t)$ at that t.

I also tried applying the magnitude of $a(t)$ to the total magnitude of $V(t)$ rather than trying to split it into components to get $V(t)=\sqrt{v_{xi}^2+(v_{yi}-gt)^2}-\int_0^t{a(t')dt'}$ but I need the velocity in component form since my next step is go integrate the y component for the y position and I will also need to solve for t later and not even mathematica can seem to solve for t in that equation.

Comment: What's the context of this question? It would make it easier to answer your question if you provide a statement of the original problem (since I'm assuming this is homework-related.)

Comment: Its actually a personal project. I'm trying to calculate how long a suicide burn would take to land a rocket and when to start burning. $a(t)$ is supposed to represent the acceleration from the engine t seconds after ignition. My plan is to set the expressions for velocity equal to 0 and solve for t which should give me the seconds it would take to kill all velocity and then figure out at what t should $a(t)$ no longer be 0 (engine ignition) so that $V(t)=0$ at the same time $P_y(t)=0$ where $P$ is position.